# Implemented method getting NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, null, printwriter

I have an implemented method which visits the node of a binary tree. I have a word class which implements this through an interface called TreeComparable.

Here is the visit method:

```
@Override
public void visit() {
    System.out.printf("%-15s%-7s", getWord(), count);
    pw.printf("%-15s%-7s", getWord(), count);
    ObjectListNode p = list.getFirstNode();
    while (p != null) {
        System.out.print(((LinePosition) p.getInfo()).getLineNumber() + "-" + ((LinePosition) p.getInfo()).getPosition() + "  ");
        pw.print(((LinePosition) p.getInfo()).getLineNumber() + "-" + ((LinePosition) p.getInfo()).getPosition() + "  ");
        p = p.getNext();
    }
    System.out.println();
    pw.println();
}
```

I am getting errors with the PrintWriter Object. I am getting a nullPointerException. I have a default constructor that is part of the class that is implementing this visit method.

This is the default constructor being used when creating a word object.

```
public Word(PrintWriter pw) {
    this.pw = pw;
}
```

Everything works if I comment out trying to write to the text file:

```
@Override
public void visit() {
    System.out.printf("%-15s%-7s", getWord(), count);
    //pw.printf("%-15s%-7s", getWord(), count);
    ObjectListNode p = list.getFirstNode();
    while (p != null) {
        System.out.print(((LinePosition) p.getInfo()).getLineNumber() + "-" + ((LinePosition) p.getInfo()).getPosition() + "  ");
        //pw.print(((LinePosition) p.getInfo()).getLineNumber() + "-" + ((LinePosition) p.getInfo()).getPosition() + "  ");
        p = p.getNext();
    }
    System.out.println();
    //pw.println();
}
```

however, for this assignment I need to print out the outputs to a text file. Why is the printwriter object not getting passed in correctly?Thanks for any input!

EDIT:
Here are a few places where I tried to call the constructor:

```
public class Query {

PrintWriter pw;

public Query(PrintWriter pw) {
    this.pw = pw;
}

public void performQuery(ObjectBinaryTree t) {

    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Search for word: ");
    pw.println("Search for word: ");
    Word word = new Word(pw);
    String input = userInput.next();

    do {

        word = new Word(input);

        if (t.searchBST(word) != null) {
            ObjectTreeNode p = t.searchBST(word);
            ObjectListNode q = ((Word) p.getInfo()).getList().getFirstNode();

            System.out.printf("%-15s%-5s", ((Word) p.getInfo()).getWord(), ((Word) p.getInfo()).getCount());
            pw.printf("%-15s%-5s", ((Word) p.getInfo()).getWord(), ((Word) p.getInfo()).getCount());
            while (q != null) {
                System.out.print(((LinePosition) q.getInfo()).getLineNumber() + "-" + ((LinePosition) q.getInfo()).getPosition() + "  ");
                q = q.getNext();
            }
            System.out.println("\nType 1 to exit, or press enter for new search: ");
            pw.println("\nType 1 to exit, or press enter for new search: ");
            input = userInput.next();
            continue;
        }

        else
            System.out.print("Word Not Found");
            System.out.println("\nType 1 to exit, or press enter for new search: ");
            pw.print("Word Not Found");
            pw.println("\nType 1 to exit, or press enter for new search: ");
            input = userInput.next();
            continue;

    } while (!input.equals("1"));
}

}
```

and:

```
public class Driver {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File("csis.txt"));

    Word word = new Word(pw);
    Xref xref = new Xref(pw);
    Query query = new Query(pw);
    xref.readWords();

    System.out.println();
    pw.println();
    query.performQuery(xref.getBinaryTree());

    pw.close();

}
```

}

EDIT:
The visit() method is part of this interface (not sure if this helps but...):

```
public interface TreeComparable {
int compareTo(Object o);
void operate(Object o);
void visit();
}
```

Comment: Where is the call to the constructor?

Comment: Show the code where you the instantiate the Word object

Comment: I tried doing it in all the classes where I created an instance of Word just to see if it would do anything, but no luck. In each class its implemented as Word word = new Word(pw);

Comment: You need to pass PrintWriter object to Word constructor. Just passing PrintWriter type variable would give you NPE

Comment: I believe I have been passing the PrintWriter object to word constructor. I've actually done it in every instance of creating a Word Object just to see if anything would happen. Nothing changed. But PrintWriter is working with all my other classes. In the above performQuery method of the Query class, the PrintWriter works fine.@Vwin

Comment: @Ybarra your question seems to have duplicated code. Please review it.

Comment: @Ybarra Where in the call stack is this happening? It looks like the `Word` you instantiate in `main` isn't the one that's erroring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
String input = userInput.next();

do {

    word = new Word(input);
```

You should be getting a compile-time error about that, but evidently `Word` has a constructor that takes a `String` rather than a `PrintWriter`, and that constructor isn't setting `pw` correctly. This assignment is throwing away the (correct) instantiation above:

```
Word word = new Word(pw);
```

It looks like you might be misunderstanding what is and isn't a static member of an object. All of the `Word` objects you instantiate with a `PrintWriter` carry around a non-null value for `pw`, but the rest have `null` unless you fix it. My guess is that your `Word(String)` constructor ignores `pw` and expects it to be set by some other call -- it won't.

Comment: You're right, I have two constructors for Word. So calling a PrintWriter object in another instance wont allow me to write to a text file?

Comment: @Ybarra The properties of a `Word` object are per-instance, not per class. Make `pw` `static` if you want every instance to access the same one.